# Page display and refresh problem in vueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a small problem with the display of the Authentication with VueJs page.
Once on the authentication User page I also have the menu which remains displayed, and once authenticated it redirects me to the Home page however when I disconnect I have the same concerns, it redirects me to the authenticationUser page but with the menu that remains displayed.
and if I do a refresh on the authenticationUser page the page remains blank without error.
I don't know if you have any idea for the cause of the problem.
Thanks in advance.

**Page App.vu**

```
<template>
    <v-app id='inspire'>
      <div v-if="user && user.sub">
        <Menu />
      </div>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import AuthentificationUser from "./views/AuthentificationUser";
import AuthenticatedUserUtils from "./utils/AuthenticatedUserUtils";
import Header from './components/common/Header';
import Menu from './components/common/Menu';
export default {
  name: "app",
  data: () => ({
    user: AuthenticatedUserUtils.user
  }),
  components: {
    AuthentificationUser,
    Menu
  },
};
</script>
enter code here
```

**Router.ts**

```
import User from '../models/User'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import AuthenticatedUserUtils from '../utils/AuthenticatedUserUtils'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/inventory',
    name: 'Inventory',
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/inventory/authentificationUser',
    name: 'AuthentificationUser',
    component: () => import('../views/AuthentificationUser.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/inventory/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue'),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/inventory/parametrage',
    name: 'Parametrage',
    component: () => import('../views/Parametrage.vue'),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/inventory/rfid',
    name: 'RFID',
    component: () => import('../views/RFID.vue'),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true,
    }
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!!to && !!to.meta && to.meta.requireAuth) {
    // TODO : voir si le cookie existe et est valide
    if (document && document.cookie) {
      const potentialCookie = document.cookie
      .split('; ')
      .find(row => row.startsWith('access_token='));

      let token = '';
      if (potentialCookie) {
        token = potentialCookie.split('=')[1];
      }

      const parsedJwt = parseJwt(token);
      if (new Date() <= new Date(parsedJwt.exp * 1000)) {
        const usr:User = new User();
        usr.created = parsedJwt.created;
        usr.sub =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parsedJwt.sub));
        usr.exp = parsedJwt.exp;
        AuthenticatedUserUtils.user = usr;
        next();
      } else {
        AuthenticatedUserUtils.user = undefined;
        // token non valide sur une page qui a besoin de l'authent
        router.push('/inventory/authentificationUser').catch(()=>{});;
      }
    } else {
      router.push('/inventory/authentificationUser').catch(()=>{});;
    }
  } else {
    // appInsights.trackPageView({ name: to.name });
    next();
  }
});
function parseJwt (token: string) {
  var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
  var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
  var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
      return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join(''));

  return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};

export default router
enter code here
```

**Menu.ts**

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer color="#80e27e" app v-model='drawer'>
    <div style="background-color: #F5F5F5; width:260px;height:63px;">
    <v-list-item-title class="text-h6" style="text-align:center; padding-top: 5%; color: #087f23;">{{ $t("label.inventaire") }}</v-list-item-title>
    </div>
    <v-list dense nav>
      <template v-for='item in items'>
        <v-list-item :key='item.text' @click="goToRoute(item.to)">
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon v-text="item.icon" style="color: #087f23;" />
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" style="color: #087f23;"/>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-list>
    <template>
      <div style="color: #087f23; margin-top: 150%;">
      <b><span block style="color: #087f23; margin-left: 23%; ">{{ $t("label.bienvenue") }} Frédéric</span></b>
      <div style="width:150px;height:35px;border:0px solid #000;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;margin-left: 20%;background-color: #F5F5F5;">
          <img v-if="checkValueCodeLangueMenu() === true" style="width:35px; height:35px; margin-left:39%; border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;" src="@/assets/fra.png"/>
          <img v-if="checkValueCodeLangueMenu() === false" style="width:27px; height:27px; margin-left:39%; margin-top:2%; border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;" src="@/assets/eng.png"/>
      </div>
      <v-btn  style="color: #087f23; margin-top: 10%;width:200px;height:35px; margin-left: 10%;" @click="logout()">
        <v-icon>mdi-logout</v-icon>
        <label>{{ $t("label.deconnexion") }}</label>
      </v-btn>
      </div>
      </template>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar app color="#4caf50">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = !drawer" style="color: #087f23;"></v-app-bar-nav-icon> 
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>`
      <v-menu offset-y>`enter code here`
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <div class="text-center">
            <v-btn icon v-on="on">
              <v-icon> mdi-earth </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="langue in languesDispo"
            :key="langue.codeLangue"
            @click="changeLocale(langue)"   
          >
          <v-list-item-title>
              <img  v-if="checkValueCodeLangue(langue.codeLangue) === true" style="width:26px; height:26px;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;vertical-align:middle" src="@/assets/fra.png"/>
              <img  v-if="checkValueCodeLangue(langue.codeLangue) === false" style="width:26px; height:26px;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;vertical-align:middle" src="@/assets/eng.png"/>
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
      <v-icon v-on:click="logout()">mdi-logout</v-icon>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main >
        <v-container fluid>
          <router-view/>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
</v-app>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n';
  import Langue from '@/models/Langue';
  import PaysUtils from '@/utils/PaysUtils';
  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Menu',
    data: () => ({
      currentPays: 'fr',
      languesDispo: PaysUtils.lstPays,
       drawer: null,
       imgLangue: null,
        items: [
          { title: 'Accueil', icon: 'mdi-home', to: '/' },
          { title: 'Paramétrage', icon: 'mdi-cog', to: '/inventory/parametrage' },
          { title: 'RFID', icon: 'mdi-help-box', to: '/inventory/rfid' },
        ],
    }),
    methods: {
        logout (){
          document.cookie = "";      
          this.$router.push('/inventory/authentificationUser').catch(()=>{});
         },
        goToRoute(route: string): void {
            this.$router.push(route);
        },
        changeLocale(langue: Langue): void {
          if (langue.codeLangue && langue.codePays) {
            this.$vuetify.lang.current = langue.codeLangue;
            i18n.locale = langue.codeLangue;
            this.currentPays = langue.codePays;
          }
        },
        checkValueCodeLangue : function(langue: String) {
          if(langue === 'fra') {
            return true
          }
          return false
        },
        checkValueCodeLangueMenu : function() {
          if(this.currentPays === 'fr'){
              return true
          }
          return false
        }
    },
  })
</script>
```

Comment: From my experience in general you should not be refreshing the browser, but doing all navigation via router links.  If you need to 'refresh' a page, include a refresh link/button to  route back to the same page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, on the other hand I did not understand what to do, can you give me an example please

Comment: I am saying that if you have a list of records on a page that include a link/route to a detail page, then include a button on the detail page that just routes back to itself.  The same link/route as in the row of the list page.  I did a quick search and found this [Vue.js 2 CRUD Application with Vue Router & Axios](https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-js-crud-app/) tutorial.  I dIdn't read it in detail, but it looks useful.

Comment: Thank you, on the other hand it does not work, when I do a refresh on the authenticationUser page, I have a blank page without error in the logs

Comment: Don't think I totally understand the problem you are describing.  I did look at your code a bit, and possibly your ```router.beforeEach()``` is causing a problem.  I have heard of that method but don't recall needing to use it.  Here is a full featured [Vue.js 2 API client app](https://github.com/UniquelySimilar/vue-client-for-spring-rest) that I wrote.  Possibly a lot to take in, but may be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, for your help